# ajax - How to receive data both html and json from server?

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have referenced [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435213/access-both-html-and-json-data-returned-from-ajax), but it doesn't solve my problem.

I'm using mvc 5 with c#. I have usually used this code to receive data from server with data type is `json`.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/MyController/MyAction",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
      if (data.result) {
         alert('successfull');
      }
      else {
         alert(data.ex);
      }
   }
});
```

and Controller code:

```
[httppost]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
   try
   {
      return Json(new { result = "true", ex = "" });
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      return Json(new { result = "false", ex = e.Message });
   }
}
```

I use this way for data type is html:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/MyController/MyAction",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "html",
   success: function (data) {
      $(".myDiv").append(data);
   }
});
```

and the Controller should be:

```
[httppost]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
   return PartialView("_MyPartialView");
}
```

My question is: Is there any way to combine all of them to one?

Something is like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/MyController/MyAction",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json" or "html",
   success: function (data) {
      if (data.result) {
         $(".myDiv").append(data);
      }
      else {
         alert(data.ex);
      }
   }
});
```

and the imagination Controller code:

```
[httppost]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
   try
   {
      return PartialView("_MyPartialView");
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      return Json(new { result = "false", ex = e.Message });
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What error do you get?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi The problem is: if the controller returns `return PartialView("_MyPartialView");`, so what is `data.result`?

Comment: @kevin, `data.result == null` means its give a paritalview result or `data.result == false` mean its give json Result, because actionResult return all type of results.

Comment: @Vijay You mean that: `if (data.result) {}` should be `if (data.result == null) {}`, don't you?

Comment: `if(data.result==null || data.result=='')
{
 $(".myDiv").append(data);
}
else
{
alert(data.ex);
}`

if result is null mean partialview output, or result have value means json result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/MyAction",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data.result) {
                        $(".myDiv").append(data);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(data.ex);
                    }
                }
        });
        });
    </script>
}
```

So if the `data` doesn't contain anonymouse object, It means that it contains the HTML returned by `PartialView`.

Comment: It doesn't need the `dataType` anymore.